# removing numeric character from data

Tags: r

I want to remove the number 0 from all the names in my data.frame.

I have tried to do it myself, however, working with strings is a first time for me.

I have tried:

```
gsub('\0', '',  df )
```

reproducible code:

```
df <- c("y2016.09", "y2010.05", "y2010.06", "y2010.07", "y2010.08", 
"y2010.09")
```

expected output

```
y2016.9 
y2010.5
y2010.6 
y2010.7
y2010.8 
y2010.9
```

Answer (score 2):

We can specify the location of `.` (`.` is a metacharacter in regex - for any character, so it is escaped `\\` to evaluate it literally) and 0 or more character of 0's is matched (`0*`), in the replacement, replace with `.` i.e. the one we removed by matching

```
sub("\\.0*", ".", df)
#[1] "y2016.9" "y2010.5" "y2010.6" "y2010.7" "y2010.8" "y2010.9"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another regex solution using lookarounds, but not as simple as the one by [@akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64361148/12158757)

```
> gsub("(?<=\\.)0+","",df,perl = TRUE)
[1] "y2016.9" "y2010.5" "y2010.6" "y2010.7" "y2010.8" "y2010.9"
```